# Entity Framework Code First default valut for bit datatype

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Using EntityFramework codefirst's latest version (4.3), I've created a table with column Enabled(bit). Then I've found out that it has a default value of false, can I set the default value to true?

I've found something weird when I renamed the column to Disabled the default value becomes null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can initialize `Enabled` to `true` in the constructor

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Enabled = true;
    }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Your `Disabled` column must a a nullable column. Hence its default value is null.